# Android:How can i know my location is accurate

Tags: android, location

I like to find current location.I also know how to find the location from `GPS` and `Network`. `GPS` is more accurate than `Network`. But when `GPS` signal is poor i like to use `Network` to get accurate location.

My question is that how can i determine which one is giving me best accurate location and my location is accurate? I have to find out correct location.

You may suggest `location.getAccuracy()`.But i don't know details about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) for a definition of `getAccuracy`

as for you question please read through this [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html), it talkes about how

ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = location updates from NETWORK_PROVIDER
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = location updates from GPS_PROVIDER

and much more, make sure to scroll down to "Maintaining a current best estimate"